# install air 2.5 sdk for flash buider4

Tags: air, flash-builder

How to install air 2.5 sdk for flash builder4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download latest AIR SDK. Find your FB installation folder. Open folder "sdks", then select sdk version you need (e.g. "4.0.0"). Unpack files from AIR SDK there (their structure should match, and they will have some common files, like "AIR SDK Readme.txt").

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps for Install new Sdk for flash Builder.

```
1.Download the sdk from adobe site.
2.Go to installation folder of flash builder
3.open sdk folder.
4.Copy old sdk folder and paste it in the sdk folder(rename it)
5.Now unzip the newly downleded sdk into that folder.(replace 
all old files while popup prompt for that).
6.Restart the Flash builder if it already run.
```

Enjoy.